# Key mapping based depending on a number of windows open

Tags: vim, window

I have this mapping set yp to:

```
noremap  <C-W>  :wq<CR>
```

and would like to make it work only when there is a single window on the screen (even if there were some other windows before, which I have 
close). How can I do it?

Comment: `<C-w>` is the leader mapping for every window navigation command. I don't think you should remap it to anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define conditional mappings with `:help :map-expr`; the condition for a single window is `winnr('$') == 1`: Ergo:

```
noremap <expr> <C-W>  winnr('$') == 1 ? ":wq<CR>" : ""
```

I've made the mapping a no-op if there are multiple windows. You can also return `"<C-w>"` then to avoid losing the very helpful CTRL-W submode (as @romainl has already remarked). I also don't understand your motivation; `:wq` only works on the current buffer; if others are open, Vim won't exit, anyway.